# How to view indoor map and floor levels using Mapkit?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, apple-maps

How to view indoor maps and its level of the publicly accessible areas like malls using MapKit?

With the following code I am able to see the building in 3D but not able to switch floor or see the indoor mmap. I am sure its indoor map is publicly accessible.

```
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        mapView.showsBuildings = true
        let mallCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.938210, -75.031590)
    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mallCoordinates, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 100) //

        let mapCamera = MKMapCamera()
        mapCamera.centerCoordinate = mallCoordinates
        mapCamera.pitch = 45
        mapCamera.altitude = 500
        mapCamera.heading = 45
    
        mapView.camera = mapCamera
```

Comment: What makes you think there's a floor under a street in New Jersey?

Comment: These are not precise coordinates. But I am sure since I checked the place here https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-indoor-maps-mall.

Comment: @ElTomato I also want to view the indoor maps, not just the floor levels

Comment: Do you see indoor maps at 40.6600° N, 74.1714° W ?